# Setting capabilities to Anaconda's python executable

Tags: python, anaconda, linux-capabilities

I've switched to Anaconda recently, but have encountered an issue. My python code uses a C++ shared library which receives raw frames from an interface. To do this, root permissions are generally required. So as not to use sudo for each execution, I generally give the python interpreter `cap_net_raw` and `cap_ipc_lock` capabilities (this is an academic setting, so no reason to worry about security, at least for now). Generally this works fine for the default python installation (I'm using Ubuntu 14.04.4), however when I try to do the same for the python executable of Anaconda (4.3.0, Python 3.6), I get the following error:

*python: error while loading shared libraries: libpython3.6m.so.1.0:
cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory*

The library is located where it should be, and `ldd` on the python executable shows that it's pointing to it. Adding it's path to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` doesn't do anything. Remove the capabilities then restores this issue.

I tried this with a clean system install of Python 3.6, and there were no issues with it.

Would appreciate any input, thanks.